# Embedded mp4 not playing in Chrome or Firefox, just Safari

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I want to embed an mp4 in my Rails 4 app.

```
=video_tag "movie.mp4", controls: true
```

This works in Safari. However, in Chrome, the play button is grayed out. In Firefox, which I never use and may not have the requisite plugin installed, it says "Video format or MIME type is not supported" in the video player box.

The video is about 100mb and was created with iMovie.

Shouldn't mp4s play in the latest Chrome and FF? Is this a problem with the way I created the mp4 in iMovie?

Edit: added image of network console:

[image]

Edit 2: If I navigate to /assets/movie.mp4, the movie still doesn't play, and this is what I get in the network console:

[image]

Comment: is it something you can share a sample to check? have you looked in the developer console (and network tool) in Chrome to see if there's an error hitting the file (MIME type might be wrong on the server for instance)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, I added a screenshot of the network console. I don't know what the second request is- there is only one line of code in my application referencing that file- nor do I know why it returned 200 for that second request, or why it's 0 B.

Comment: @bevanb Hi, same situation here, have you solved this issue finally?